# Calculte expected value of uniform joint density

Tags: probability

> Random variables X ≥ 0 and Y ≥ 0 are uniformly distributed on the region bounded by the x and y axes, and > the curve y = 1 − x2. Calculate E(XY ).

When calculating the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = c$ for $ 0<x,y,\quad  y \leq 1-x^2$, why is it wrong to solve the equation $c\frac{\pi(1)^2}{4} = 1 $ for c? I thought since they're each uniformly distributed, they are jointly uniform as well? What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: From where does $\pi$ come from?

Comment: Note that $y=1-x^2$ describes a parabola, not a semicircle. A semicircle would be $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh rightt, when I drew it it looked like a quarter circle with radius 1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to regard the bounds. In general we have the equation

$$\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)\, dy \,dx=1
\end{align}$$

In your case it is

$$\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber   \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x^2} c \, dy \,dx=1
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  c\cdot \int_{0}^{1} 1-x^2 \,dx=1
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  c\cdot  \left[x-\frac13\cdot x^3\right]_0^1=1
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  c\cdot  \frac23=1\Rightarrow c=\frac32
\end{align}$$

Integral should be corrected

Comment: @Aurora . Thanks for spotting. We can see how blindly some OPs accept answers.